# Pattern for special date in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need pattern for these date:

```
14-09-2016 10:00 
16/09/16 10:00
2016/09/16 10:00
```

This is my pattern:

```
var patt = new RegExp("(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[012])-[0-9]{4}");
var res = patt.test(date1);
```

I don't know how can I add space and others characters to my code
Can U help me ?:)

Comment: We can help you, but you should show the regular expression(s) you have tried.

Comment: `\s` is for spaces. `\/` for slashes. I recommend using a website like https://regex101.com/ to test your RegExes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following expression. It is quite long as it matches the third format separately.

```
^(?:(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])([-\/])(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\1\d{2,4}|\d{2,4}([-\/])(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\2(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))\s(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$
```

Leave out the start `^` and end `$` if you need to find and match these dates in a larger string.

See demo on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uJDBe4/1)